# PHP equivalent of a Node encryption function

Tags: php, node.js, encryption, openssl

I am trying to get a php equivalent of this node function to be able to encrypt some data in php before decrypting it in node

```js
/**
    * Encrypts an object with aes-256-cbc to use as a token
    * @param {any} data An object to encrypt
    * @param {string} secret The secret to encrypt the data with
    * @returns {string}
    */
static encrypt(data, secret) {
    const iv = randomBytes(16);
    const cipher = createCipheriv('aes-256-cbc', secret, iv);
    return `${cipher.update(JSON.stringify(data), 'utf8', 'base64') + cipher.final('base64')}.${iv.toString('base64')}`;
}
```

This is the php function I have come up with, along with the necessary helper functions

```php
/**
 * Encrypts an object with aes-256-cbc to use as a token
 * @param $data An object to encrypt
 * @param $secret The secret to encrypt data with
 * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
 */
public function encrypt($data, $secret)
{
    $method = 'AES-256-CBC';

    $data = static::getPaddedText($data);
    $iv             = static::generateIv();

    $ciphertext     = openssl_encrypt(json_encode($data), $method, $secret, OPENSSL_RAW_DATA, $iv);
    $ciphertext_64  = base64_encode(utf8_encode($ciphertext));
    $iv_64          = base64_encode($iv);
    return "$ciphertext_64.$iv_64";
}

private static function getPaddedText(string $plainText): string
{
    $blocksize = 8;

    $textLength = strlen($plainText);
    if ($textLength % $blocksize) {
        $plainText = str_pad($plainText, $textLength + $blocksize - $textLength % $blocksize, "\0");
    }
    return $plainText;
}

public static function generateIv(): string
{
    $ivLength = 16;
    $success = false;
    $random = openssl_random_pseudo_bytes($ivLength, $success);
    if (!$success) {
        $random = random_bytes($ivLength);
    }
    return $random;
}
```

But I dont think it is exactly the same as when decrypting it with this function

```js
/**
    * Decrypts an object with aes-256-cbc to use as a token
    * @param {string} token An data to decrypt
    * @param {string} secret The secret to decrypt the data with
    * @returns {any}
    */
static decrypt(token, secret) {
    const [data, iv] = token.split('.');
    const decipher = createDecipheriv('aes-256-cbc', secret, Buffer.from(iv, 'base64'));
    return JSON.parse(decipher.update(data, 'base64', 'utf8') + decipher.final('utf8'));
}
```

I get this error `EVP_DecryptFinal_ex:wrong final block length`

Comment: (1) Test your _original_ PHP function _after_ you have removed `utf8_encode`. (2) Use a 32 bytes key for testing, since you specified AES-256 (otherwise PHP will explicitly pad `0x00` values at the end, which must of course be taken into account in the NodeJS code) (3) PHP uses the reliable PKCS7 padding by default (unless you disablable it, which you don't have), so additional padding isn't necessary.

Comment: 1. I added `utf8_encode` as a debug step, 2. what do you mean by a 32 bytes key, as in the iv string? if so I tried that but got an error saying 32 bytes is too long

Comment: AES-256 uses a 32 bytes key and a 16 bytes IV. _...but got an error saying 32 bytes is too long_ From which code?

Comment: @Topaco I set the iv length to 32 which didnt work, wasnt sure what you meant by a 32 byte key

Comment: The key is the 3rd parameter of `openssl_encrypt` for which you used `testsecret`! For AES-256 the key must be 32 bytes = 256 bits! The IV must be 16 bytes (everything else doesn't work). See [here](https://pastebin.com/Eu75GP7C) and [here](https://pastebin.com/7F51zy6C) and test it [here](https://paiza.io/en/projects/new?language=php) and [here](https://repl.it/languages/nodejs).

Comment: @Topaco sorry that was just an example, my actual secret is 32 bytes, it is similar to this `lpMyls8TA149sn3yi6daA4zfbl4p_Mdk`

Comment: Yep, that's fine. You can also use this key in both linked codes. Of course it works as well.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you aren't padding your text with nulls to ensure you have block sizes that are exactly eight characters long. In pother words, your string needs to be a multiple of eight in length. Padding your string with nulls will accomplish that for you without changing its value.

```
class AES256Encryption
{
    public const BLOCK_SIZE = 8;
    public const IV_LENGTH = 16;
    public const CIPHER = 'AES-256-CBC';

    public static function generateIv(): string
    {
            $success = false;
            $random = openssl_random_pseudo_bytes(static::IV_LENGTH, $success);
            if (!$success) {
                $random = random_bytes(static::IV_LENGTH);
            }
            return $random;
    }

    private static function getPaddedText(string $plainText): string
    {
        $textLength = strlen($plainText);
        if ($textLength % static::BLOCK_SIZE) {
            $plainText = str_pad($plainText, $textLength + static::BLOCK_SIZE - $textLength % static::BLOCK_SIZE, "\0");
        }
        return $plainText;
    }

    public static function encrypt(string $plainText, string $key, string $iv): string
    {
        $plainText = static::getPaddedText($plainText);
        return base64_encode(openssl_encrypt($plainText, static::CIPHER, $key, OPENSSL_RAW_DATA, $iv));
    }

    public static function decrypt(string $encryptedText, string $key, string $iv): string
    {
        return openssl_decrypt(base64_decode($encryptedText), static::CIPHER, $key, OPENSSL_RAW_DATA, $iv);
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
$key = 'secretkey';
$iv = AES256Encryption::generateIv();
$text = 'The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog';
$encryptedText = AES256Encryption::encrypt($text, $key, $iv);
$decryptedText = AES256Encryption::decrypt($encryptedText, $key, $iv);

printf('Original Text: %s%s', $text, PHP_EOL);
printf('Encrypted    : %s%s', $encryptedText, PHP_EOL);
printf('Decrypted    : %s%s', $decryptedText, PHP_EOL);
```

Output:

```
Original Text: The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog
Encrypted    : 1J+0tGHzn67WA7kJGjp9malmv0w+tcl0t8YnC+F9Y9IZWMDeBH4+k9TyuznF77cWe1SGUWa6Pb6r/i0xmH+ajg==
Decrypted    : The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog
```

Your usage:

```
// Your encoding usage:
$key = 'secret';
$iv = AES256Encryption::generateIv();
$text = 'The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog';
$encryptedText = AES256Encryption::encrypt($text, $key, $iv);
$finalString = $encryptedText . bin2hex($iv);

// Your decoding usage:
$iv = hex2bin(substr($finalString, -32, 32));
$decryptedText = AES256Encryption::decrypt($encryptedText, $key, $iv);

printf('Original Text : %s%s', $text, PHP_EOL);
printf('Encrypted     : %s%s', $encryptedText, PHP_EOL);
printf('Encrypted w/Iv: %s%s', $finalString, PHP_EOL);
printf('Decrypted     : %s%s', $decryptedText, PHP_EOL);
```

Output:

```
Original Text : The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog
Encrypted     : +JsjXFPdyTycYrc2fOb1edLKNksEUHzEGxwRewBlA8yxBWZZV2y/EVIwk0g9g17dtxAaTGZvYaf2y9+oTCvLWg==
Encrypted w/Iv: +JsjXFPdyTycYrc2fOb1edLKNksEUHzEGxwRewBlA8yxBWZZV2y/EVIwk0g9g17dtxAaTGZvYaf2y9+oTCvLWg==54993615360ff641a952a553e1500568
Decrypted     : The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog
```

Generating the IV can be more robust as `random_bytes()` can throw an exception.

Comment: Just implemented that but I'm still getting the same error

Comment: Can you post the exact code you are using including the text you are trying to encrypt?

Comment: Its called by including the trait and doing `$this->encrypt($token, $secret)` where `$token` and `$secret` are both strings similar to this `edRyls8PL382sn3yi6daA4zfbl4p_Mdk`

Comment: Unfortunately that's not enough to go on

Comment: I'm not sure what else you want to see, I'm not going to give the exact text as it is discord related tokens and strings which I don't want made public

Comment: You can make an example with different text just like I did in my example. The actual text you want to encrypt/decrypt is irrelevant.

Comment: I see your problem: you are mucking up the data after you pad it. You're json encoding it. Do that *before* you apply the padding.

Comment: That didnt solve it, an example is using `testtoken` and `testsecret` as the `data` and `secret` variables, the output being `w7nCpAbCs8KzLsKqwpzDt8KFwpvClcKfwrHCrR7CpcO6acOGZsOhaV8HPsKgNTPDlMOrwqk=.n4Y+S1eGGyIsMZH2kf+37Q==` which is then passed to the decrypt function as shown above which is where it breaks

Comment: That `.` looks very suspicious. That shouldn't be there.

Comment: It should, I put it there

Comment: The decrypt method splits the token by that `.` to get the data and the iv

Comment: Without seeing how you generate and decrypt those values there isn't anything I can do to help.

Comment: I dont know what else I can provide you with to help

Comment: I'm thinking it is an issue with the compatibility between the node encrypt function and the php encrypt function as the php encrypt function needs to be exactly the same as the node equivalent to allow the decrypt function to work

Comment: Did you figure it out?